# nested div innertext returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object in HtmlAgilitypack

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack, html-parser

I am trying to get the value of a nested div using `HtmlAgilitypack`.my html code is like this :

[image]

here is my code :

```
        var val = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='journal-content-article']/div[@class='news_page max']/div[@class='news_page_wrapper']/div[@class='news_page_content']/div[@class='news_content']/div[@class='news_content_container']").InnerText;
```

I need the innertext of `news_content_container` .but this line of code return `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

This returns error:

```
        var val = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='journal-content-article']/div[@class='news_page max']").InnerText;
```

This returns value but not expected value:

```
        var val = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='journal-content-article']").InnerText;
```

Comment: The object reference not set error is obviously because SelectSingleNode returns null and you try to get InnerText property. You should try selecting the element step by step to find the problem.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz yes you are right but i use the xpath to get the element value

Comment: Okey, but you need to debug by trying to select the element step by step to find where SelectSingleNode returns null. It may be a typo issue or something.

Comment: I updated the post ,as i said the second div returns null reference ,my question is why ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times the HTML content of a page is not well-formed. Inspecting with browser does not show the actual HTML received from the server. You can find the actual HTML in `Source` tab of inspector.

You need to fix not well-formed HTML before passing it to HtmlAgilitypack. Here is [a site you can use](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fixmyhtml-online-tool-cleaning-html-code/) (You can use by sending HTTP Post to site and get the "fine html" from response)